# How to use the push property of an empty array?

Tags: typescript, angular-cli

I'm getting the "Property 'push' dos not exist on type '{}'." error, this is my code:

```
  messages: string[] = [];

  add(message: string) {
    this.messages.push(message);
  }
```

How can I solve this?

---

This is the code of the whole file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MessageService {
  messages: string[] = [];

  add(message: string) {
    this.messages.push(message);
  }

  clear() {
    this.messages = [];
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some more code? The error states that your trying to push to an object, not an array

Comment: `this.messages` is not an array. Without seeing more code it's impossible to say why, could be an issue with binding or initialization or it could be that you're setting `this.messages` to an object at some other point in the code. Can you show the block with the surrounding code? [The code displayed does work when isolated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20messages%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20add(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.messages.push(message)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Looks like something is changing your `array` literal to an `object` literal. If you are using an IDE, adding the `private` modifier to the `messages` property might reveal the culprit.

Comment: This might be an IDE bug, are you using any IDE. Because this should work in typescript just fine.

Comment: I'm using VSCode

Answer (score 0):

```
messages: string[] = [];
```

is wrongly declared try something like

```
var message = [];
```

Comment: typescript is superset of javascript everything that work in javascript will work in typescript.